# Magento 2 admin catalog save button not working

Tags: magento2, product, admin, magento2.2, catalog

yesterday I have imported some products in my store, today when I was trying to do some changes in product edit functionality is not working. 
Even the Save button is not clickable

I checked logs no exception, nothing in logs.

It's working for all the other products except the imported products

Comment: maybe some field in a certain section does not pass js validation and that's why the save button does not submit anything.

Comment: but i dnt get any error message and i checked all the attributes

Comment: Would you check your console for js errors?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- Clear cache (`php bin/magento cache:flush`) and (`php bin/magento cache:clean`)
- If this not solve your problem you may try to `remove all static content` and `redeploy`